# Whats the best way to remove a ton of buildings?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm preparing to move my living quarters which means that I need to remove a ton of beds, cabinets, chests and doors. I *really* dont want to go to each building and press <kbd>x</kbd>. Is there a way I can set an remove buildings from an area? Similar to remove construction.

Comment: Magma is neither the best nor the quickest way but it is the most fun.

Answer (score 1):

Far as I know, without any 3rd party mods, you'll have to remove them all individually.

Comment: What mods can I use?